# Compile a C / SDL program with Visual C++ 2013 from the Command Line

Tags: c, sdl, cl

How do I that? I don't want to use the Visual Studio IDE, yet I want to use the provided compiler (cl.exe) and the Developer Command Prompt for VS2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cl.exe /Wall /Tc main.c
```

will generate a proper `main.exe`.

and before that:

- ensure that c:\Windows\System32 is in the PATH
- execute `vcvarsall.bat` from your install directory of VC

If you want to use a library (e.g., SDL) you need to list the libraries with `/link` option (library paths can be added with `/LIBPATH`) and the library include directories with `/I` option.

Comment: Thanks! Also, maybe I won't need to execute the .bat file, since the Developer Command Prompt sets up the environment variables for me, right? Thanks again.

Comment: @FernandoKarpinski I don't know the Developer Command Prompt, but I think it's a fair assumption.

Answer (score 5):

I used to do it to via command line

```
cl /EHsc /MD  main.cpp /Fetest.exe /I F:\C++_Libraries\SDL2\SDL2-2.0.3\include /link /LIBPATH:F:\C++_Libraries\SDL2\SDL2-2.0.3\lib\x86 SDL2.lib SDL2main.lib /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
```

Comment: `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` works as an alternative to `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` if you don't want console output.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem as well. I had to do two things to fix it:

1. Add the `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` as mentioned in previous answers.
   Note that this gives a different error along the lines of `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CommandLineToArgvW referenced in function main_getcmdline`. This can be solved with doing the next step.
2. Link the `Shell32.lib` as mentioned in the SDL forums: https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/windows-build-fails-with-missing-symbol-imp-commandlinetoargvw/27256/2

So my final command line command looks like:

```
cl.exe /Zi /I "C:\...\SDL2-2.0.12\include" sdl_program.c /link  "C:\...\lib\x64\SDL2main.lib" "C:\...\lib\x64\SDL2.lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64\shell32.lib" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
```